# Python: Reading excel file but Index should be DateTime not Sequential Numbers

Tags: python, anaconda

Hey I am loading in data from an excel sheet. The excel sheet has 5 columns. The first colume is a DateTime, and the next 4 are datasets corresponding to that time. Here is the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel (r'path\test.xlsx', sheet_name='2018')
```

I thought it would load it in such that the DateTime is the index, but instead it has another column called Index which is just a set of numbers going from 0 up to the end of the array. How do I have the DateTime column be the index and remove the other column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this after you read the excel, it is two extra lines

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") 
"""
Assuming that Datetime is the name of the Datetime column and the format of the column is  07/15/2020 12:24:45 -"%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"
if the format of the date time string is different change the format mentioned 
"""
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Datetime'])) 
"""
This will set the index as datetime index
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this problem:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel (r'path\test.xlsx', sheet_name='2018')
df = df.set_index('timestamp') #Assuming thename of your datetime column is timestamp
```

You can try this method for setting the Datetime column as the index.